# Why is some part of the mesh getting "hidden" or "cut out"

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

Some parts of my mesh just gets hidden or cut out of my view. I don't know why this is happening is this is the first time this has happened to me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps try to change the Clip End ratio in the N menu > View